# Is it possible to center a div with another element that wouldn't affect the centering?

Tags: html, css, position

Is it possible to center a div in a div and have an element on the right in the first div but not effect the centering of the other element. For the image below, could Text1 still be in the center of the blue div independent of Text2 being on the right?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pXav.png

(Text1 is relatively centered when there isn't that much text in it but it is still slightly off center.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use absolute positioning on the top/right element. Just make the parent `position: relative` and on the element on the right, you can use `top: 50%; translateY(-50%);` to vertically center it.

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  text
  <span>foo</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `position: absolute;` with `right: 0;` and `top: 0;`

(`margin-top: 100px;` not needed, it just adds some space at top)

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  background: aqua;
  height: 100px;
}

.right-top {
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">TEXT1
  <div class="right-top">TEXT2</div>
</div>
```